# What table_ids to use in YugabyteDB asynchronous replication sink cluster?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Hello,

I am trying to setup unidirectional async replication, for that I am bootstrapping the sink cluster. For creating checkpoints, I need to execute the following command :

```
./bin/yb-admin -master_addresses <source_universe_master_addresses> bootstrap_cdc_producer <comma_separated_source_universe_table_ids>
```

Can someone confirm if I need to include `table_ids` of only User tables or shall I include all User, Index and System tables under `comma_separated_source_universe_table_ids`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include User tables and indexes only. System tables are automatically handled.